# Non-String values in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn causing DataErrors in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a programmtically filled DataGridView with some `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` entries. These ComboBoxes hold custom types that have their `ToString()` overwritten to hide their internal guts from the user.

The Problem: whenever I change the value of the ComboBox and select another cell, the `CellValidating` is called, the FormattedValue is the string-result of my custom FooBar.ToString() (should be ok). In `CellEndEdit`, the ValueType is suddenly a string and not my custom type anymore and I get error either watching row.Cell-Member in VS or doing a mouse-over on the changed cell (translated from german):

"DataGridView-Exception: `System.ArgumentException`: The `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`-Value is invalid. Handle the DataError-Exception to replace this dialog"

This is how the column is constructed - colFoo is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`:

```
    dataGridInstance.Columns[1].CellTemplate.Value = new FooBar("bla", 31);
    dataGridInstance.Columns[1].CellTemplate.ValueType = typeof(FooBar);

    foreach (FooBar foo in FooBarArray)
            colSymbol.Items.Add(sym);
```

The Grid gets filled like this:

```
    foreach (FooLine line in SomeFooLineArray)
    { 
        DataGridViewRow newRow = ((DataGridViewRow)dataGridInstance.RowTemplate.Clone());
        newRow.Cells[1].Value = line.Foo; // FooBar instance field
        dataGridInstance.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
```

Any experiments in `CellValidating` or `CellFormatting` failed, I always get this message.

How can I add custom types into the existing `DataGridView` without overwriting too much? Almost every other Component (including dropboxes) supports custom types just fine, only the step of copying the value from the Combo to the grid seams to be the problem.

As asked, the FooBar-implementation looks like this:

```
 internal class FooBar {
        private readonly int id;
        private readonly string name;
        internal FooBar(string n, int i) 
        { 
              id = i; name = n;
        }
        public override string ToString() 
        {
              return name;
        }
 }
```

It does a little bit more, but that is the meaningful functionality encapsulated.

Comment: can you paste the overriden ToString() code that you have in question..

Comment: Well, after spending more time in investigation, I found out that this is indeed no unknown problem - a solution with custom data bound to the grid was proposed [here (Google Groups)](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms.databinding/browse_thread/thread/4b7fe5a2274e0d46?pli=1). Sadly, it does not work for me because I am not using a data source but filling the combobox myself. I got around the issue using strings again and making sure that there are no duplicate FooBar instances with the same `Name` used.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the

```
internal FooBar(string n, int i)
{
   id = i; name = n;
} 

to read like this 

internal FooBar(string n, int i)
{
   this.id = i; this.name = n;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this does not matter, because there can't be any parameter accidently taken as member variable. Anyway - in the code, I do have `this.`-calls due to better readability. I have just put some shorter excerpt in here. My suspect is more the `DataGridView` I use and maybe a missing overwrite to prevent putting the `FormattedValue` into a Cell value instead of the actual data instance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've just encountered this problem and I hope the solution is useful.

Firstly, `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` works great if you are using strings. The idea of having a ComboBox using objects is great (and just what I wanted) but if that's what you want then there are a few hurdles you need to jump through (possibly because the developers forgot).

The first one is to set the `ValueType` of the column (which you are doing in your code), i.e.:

```
dataGridInstance.Columns[1].CellTemplate.ValueType = typeof(FooBar);
```

or you can set it directly on the column:

```
dataGridInstance.Columns[1].ValueType = typeof(FooBar);
```

The second bit (and this is what you are missing) is that you need a way of converting from a string back to an instance of your data class FooBar. You do this by providing a custom event for `CellParsing`, which should look something like this:

```
private void dataGridInstance_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DesiredType == typeof(ListItem))
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridInstance.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            foreach (object item in comboCell.Items)
            {
                if (item.ToString() == e.Value.ToString())
                {
                    e.Value = item;
                    e.ParsingApplied = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's it.

One gotcha: yes, if two objects have the same `.ToString()` representation then this won't tell them apart (but that's a limitation inherent with the control). So if you can then make sure the string representation is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your columns should have same data type

Let Say

TableForComboColumn
id Int32
name Varchar

TableWithComboColumn

id Int32
TableForComboColumn_id Int16  --> **this should be Int32 also**